# concatenate same string to all elements of array or Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an `np.array` of integers and a single `str` and I want a pd.Series that is of type `str` with the single `str` prepended to the each element of the `np.array`. Is there a way to do this without creating a big list consisting of the `str`repeated the appropirate number of times? Something akin to numpy broadcasting would be ideal.

I tried `pandas.Series.str.cat` and `np.core.defchararray.add` but both of these only do element wise addition of equal length `Series`/`array`.

The following is an example of the functionality I want:

```
# This is not code that will actually run!
nums = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
name = "name "

result = concat_one_to_many(name, nums)
```

In the end I should end up with a `pd.Series` with the following values

```
"name 1"
"name 2"
"name 3"
"name 4"
"name 5"
```

This has to be as fast as possible. That is the reason I am avoiding for loops or python list comprehensions. If it is not possible to avoid these, what would the fastest way be to implement them?

Comment: `name+pd.Series(nums).astype(str)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a pd.Series, you can just add a string to a pandas series and it will add it to each element:

```
numsAsSeries = pd.Series(nums)
wantedResult = name + numsAsSeries.astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use the `map` function.

```py
new_l = pd.Series(map(lambda x: name+str(x), nums))
```

The map function will iterate over the array `nums` and apply the defined function over each element. Here, the lambda function will apply the operation `name + str(x)`, where x is an element of the `nums` array. Wrapping the whole function with `pd.Series` will return a pandas Series with default indices.

Answer (score 1):

`np.char.replace` is what you need, but you must give it an array of strings and not of a numeric type:

```
>>> np.char.replace(np.array(nums, dtype=np.str), '', 'name ', 1)
array(['name 1', 'name 2', 'name 3', 'name 4', 'name 5'], dtype='<U6')
```